# Unusual email sent in Moodle (reports/insights)

Tags: moodle

I have Moodle server configured to password reset using a Gmail account. Recently I had to migrate all the Moodle websites to a new CentOS 7 server (The Postfix was active with default configurations). Suddenly all the teachers were received thousands of emails subjected "Students at risk in 'Course Name'" with the body,

```
>Hi "Teacher name",
>A number of students in "Course Name" have never accessed the course.
>
>View insight (this is a link to 'https://my.moodle.url/report/insights/insights.php?modelid=4&contextid=14517')
```

One Teacher informed me this is happened due to Insights module and he deactivated the same module. I also deactivated the Postfix. Then everything was fine for about a week.

Today from another Moodle website in the same server has sent an email to another teacher subjected 'Upcoming courses have no teachers or students' and the body,

> Hi 'Teacher name',
>
> Courses with start dates in the next week have been
>   identified as having no teacher or student enrolments.
>
> View insight (Linked to
>   https://my.moodle.url/report/insights/insights.php?modelid=2&contextid=1)
>
> Reading this in an email? Download the mobile app and receive
>   notifications on your mobile device. (Linked to
>   'https://download.moodle.org/mobile?version=2019111803.02&lang=en&iosappid=633359593&androidappid=com.moodle.moodlemobile')

Please kindly support me to solve this issue. Is my server/ Moodle websites hacked?

Server configurations:

- CentOS 7 (Linux my.host.name 3.10.0-1127.8.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue
  May 12 16:57:42 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux)
- Nginx 1.16.1
- php 7.2.31
- Moodle 3.8

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a setting that must be still activated in Moodle adminitration. You can search for the key-word `enableanalytics` and turn this setting off.

The server may not send any of those emails after that.
The documentation of this tool can be found here : https://docs.moodle.org/38/en/Analytics_settings

Comment: Thank you. I'll check this.

Comment: Please consider marking accepting the response if it solved your problem. If not, can you give further information ?

Comment: It seems like the issue is solved. Thanks a lot for your kind support. I have marked this as accepted.